# Mysql connect in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need connect in two tables... Help me please!

```
  <?php
    $tabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rankpvp ORDER BY ratio DESC LIMIT 1");

     while($pvp = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabela)){

     $classe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM char WHERE char_id = '".$pvp['char_id']."'");

     echo ' classe: '.$classe['class'].'<br> Nome: '.$pvp['name'].'<br> Pontos: '.$pvp['ratio'].'<br> Kills: '.$pvp['kills'].'<br>   ';   }    ?>
```

Comment: Your second query is lacking the fetch_assoc. You shuold also use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: how i can put this information in my code?

Comment: after `$classe = mysql_query`..., do this: `$classe = $mysql_fetch_row($classe)`

Comment: $classe = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM char WHERE char_id = '".$pvp['char_id']."'");
$classe = $mysql_fetch_row($classe);                                                                     Dont Worked...

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors in your code?

Comment: The problem are in this line:

Comment: $classe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM char WHERE char_id = '".$pvp['char_id']."'");

Comment: Yes but what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with one query

```
SELECT * FROM `char` WHERE char_id = (SELECT char_id FROM rankpvp ORDER BY ratio DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Note that char is a reserved word so it will have to be wrapped in back ticks. Maybe this is the actual problem you ran into (syntax error) rather than a problem with your while loop. Nevertheless, one query is the right way

Comment: and what exactly does 'Dont worked ... mean'?? Do you get an error??